# .htaccess is not working even when i change Allowoverride to All

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have  searched several docs here and everywhere on Google but to no avail
i have added a .htaccess file to my default document root (/var/www/html) on apache2 running on ubuntu 16.0.
In my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file  i have also tried doing this
FROM:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But my .htaccess file is not executing...i have tried adding some sort of dummy text to my .htaccess file but it is still not working.I have checked the validity of my .htaccess file on http://www.htaccesscheck.com/ and my .htaccess file was ok..

this a copy of my .htaccess file

```
#Dont touch

# Indexing index.php

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html


# Error pages 

    ErrorDocument 400 /errorfiles/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /errorfiles/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /errorfiles/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /errorfiles/404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /errorfiles/500.html

# disable directory browsing

    Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
```

This is what  my error log says

```
[Fri Jan 12 11:35:54.273813 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25427:tid 13978013479$
[Fri Jan 12 11:35:54.273873 2018] [core:notice] [pid 25427:tid 139780134791040]$
[Fri Jan 12 11:39:52.533648 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25427:tid 13978013479$
[Fri Jan 12 11:39:53.594378 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25656:tid 13991752895$
[Fri Jan 12 11:39:53.594440 2018] [core:notice] [pid 25656:tid 139917528958848]$
[Fri Jan 12 11:40:49.182465 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25656:tid 13991752895$
[Fri Jan 12 11:40:50.242188 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27360] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 11:40:50.242239 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27360] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 11:40:51.521464 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27360] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 11:40:52.645238 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27476] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 11:40:52.645278 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27476] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 11:41:05.370691 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27476] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 11:41:06.427807 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27561] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 11:41:06.427850 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27561] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 11:46:15.963404 2018] [:error] [pid 27597] [client 41.66.255.110:35$
[Fri Jan 12 12:06:58.048553 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27561] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 12:06:59.130686 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27713] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 12:06:59.130727 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27713] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:43.402867 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27713] AH00169: cau$
```

**sorry about that, this is the continuation**

```
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:43.402867 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27713] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:44.479303 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27935] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:44.479341 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27935] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:48.447223 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27935] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:49.503253 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27995] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 12:39:49.503294 2018] [core:notice] [pid 27995] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 12:40:09.668870 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28002] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 12:42:08.004183 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27995] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 12:42:09.064352 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28058] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 12:42:09.064394 2018] [core:notice] [pid 28058] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 13:14:10.396661 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28058] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 13:14:11.444968 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28191] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 13:14:11.445006 2018] [core:notice] [pid 28191] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 13:15:23.882928 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28196] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 13:18:06.442135 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28191] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 13:19:41.544214 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28282] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 13:19:41.544256 2018] [core:notice] [pid 28282] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 14:12:06.208682 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28282] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 14:12:07.286856 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28502] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 14:12:07.286897 2018] [core:notice] [pid 28502] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 14:12:59.228236 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28508] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 14:20:17.281456 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28505] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 14:20:53.223902 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28502] AH00169: cau$
[Fri Jan 12 14:20:54.282339 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28570] AH00163: Apa$
[Fri Jan 12 14:20:54.282384 2018] [core:notice] [pid 28570] AH00094: Command li$
[Fri Jan 12 14:20:59.132006 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28575] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 14:27:17.987127 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28576] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 14:27:35.697848 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28574] [client 41.66.255.11$
[Fri Jan 12 14:28:05.961142 2018] [core:alert] [pid 28573] [client 188.166.189.$
```

**I found my last five errors having this as a  continuation since my errors are truncated and i dont know how to copy everything here**

```
 /var/www/html/.htaccess: Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
```

Comment: Did you restart your apache server or reload the config after you changed the directives?

Comment: I did sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Can you post a copy of your `.htaccess` file to your question?

Comment: Is this really Apache 2.2, as you have tagged, or is it Apache 2.4, as one might think on Ubuntu 16.x? And, what version of Ubuntu is it really? _There is no such thing as Ubuntu 16.0_.

Comment: Apache/2.4.18................. Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: How did you determine that it doesn't work?

Comment: I get an internal server error when i refresh the page after changing the  AllowOverride to All but i dont get any error message when  AllowOverride is none

Comment: If you get an internal server error look at the error log of your server. There will be a clear message what's wrong.

Comment: From my .htaccess i want apache to pick index.php over index.html.When i change AllowOverride  to All it dasn't work as expected but rather defaults to chosing index.html.Both files are in the root folder /var/www/html.When i do  Mydomain/index.php i get the internal server error message in the browser

Comment: and when i check my error log from

Comment: sudo nano /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: The rest of the log file lines would be most helpful.

Comment: Especially since the rest of the log file lines are the parts that actually _say_ what is the error.

Comment: _Look_ at the log files you are posting! They are **all truncated**, showing only the first few characters of each line, and **not** the characters that _say_ what is going on.

Comment: you are right just realised it ......i am a novice and new to linux is there any way to grap eevrything and then post them here

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it myself thanks alot esp. all who helped me out
in my .htaccess file i changed:

From:

```
Options ExecCGI Includes IncludesNOEXEC SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes
```

To:
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes
since the error says  Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may